# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting this error while running a hibernate application.

```
Apr 19, 2017 1:05:44 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
Apr 19, 2017 1:05:44 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException:     Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.manoj.java.session.HibernateSession.main(HibernateSession.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.testing.cache.CachingRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 8 more
```

Here is my hibernate cfg file.

```
<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sys as sysdba</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">oracle</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.manoj.java.hibernate.UserDetails"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have tried disabling second level cache but it is of no use. I could not find how is it taking this CacheRegionFactory even though I am not using it in hibernate config file. Could anybody please help me with this